# Web Panel for Sikulix Bot

Tags: python, virtual-machine, panel, jython, sikuli

I have created a game bot with SIKULIX, is it possible to create a web panel or dashboard that controls the bot I created from SIKULIX? if yes, how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible you could make a page in your webpanel '/bot' and the only output that page has is the action you want your bot to do and control that with a web panel. your bot could get that action through a http request